Azure Data Factory Lookup and For Each Parameterize with Data Flow
I have a Data Factory Pipeline that I want to have iterate through the rows of a SQL Lookup activity. I have narrowed the query down to 2 columns and 14 rows.
But I am getting error as mentioned below.
Error Image
Foreach1
Foreach2
Can you please help me resolve this issue?
I am trying to covert the parquet file into csv file.

The error implies that the data types might not be the same, have you checked that?
